# TSS calculation in SDMtune

Tags: maxent

I am using the TSS to evaluate my MaxEnt model built using the R package SDMtune. I am wondering what threshold is used to calculate the TSS? I know the formula to calculate the TSS, but it is not clear which threshold is used by SDMtune. I see a range of options in the MaxEnt model report. I have tried looking for the answer to this question in the SDMtune R package documentation and in several help forums. Can anyone here help me?

Kind Regards,
Marissa.